# How am I structuring my bubbles incorrectly in Pixi.js?

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, vite, pixi.js

I'm running into an issue with my bubble structure in Pixi.js. They are rendering correctly on the page but are overlapping with the data structure from my backend. How can I structure my code so that the timelines do not overlap?

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const PixiTimeline2 = ({allTimelines}) => {

    // Create a reference for the container and the app
    const containerRef = useRef();
    let app;

    // Define the renderTimeline function
    const renderTimeline = (timelineData) => {
        console.log('Rendering timeline with', timelineData.length, 'events');
        // Group events by year and month
        const eventsByYearAndMonth = {};
        
        timelineData.forEach((event) => {
            const date = new Date(event.startDate || event.date);
            const year = date.getFullYear();
            const month = date.getMonth();
            if(!eventsByYearAndMonth[year]){
                eventsByYearAndMonth[year] = {}
            }
            if(!eventsByYearAndMonth[year][month]){
                eventsByYearAndMonth[year][month] = [];
            }
            eventsByYearAndMonth[year][month].push(event);
        });
        console.log('Events grouped by year and month:', eventsByYearAndMonth);


        const bubbleSize = 10;
        const spacingX = 30;
        const spacingY = 30;
        
        const years = Object.keys(eventsByYearAndMonth);
        const maxEventsInMonth = Math.max(1,...years.map(year => Object.values(eventsByYearAndMonth[year]).map(month => month.length).flat()));
        const totalMonths = years.reduce((acc, year) => acc + Object.keys(eventsByYearAndMonth[year]).length, 0);

        
        const maxX = totalMonths * spacingX;
        const maxY = maxEventsInMonth * spacingY;

        let currentX = (app.screen.width - maxX) / 2;
        let currentY = (app.screen.height - maxY) / 2;
        
        
        
        const timelineColors = ['#FF5733', '#33FF57', '#5733FF', '#FF33D4', '#33D4FF', '#D4FF33'];
        
        // Render bubbles for each year and month
        Object.keys(eventsByYearAndMonth).forEach((year, yearIndex) => {
            currentX = (app.screen.width - maxX) / 2;
            Object.keys(eventsByYearAndMonth[year]).forEach((month, monthIndex) => {
                const events = eventsByYearAndMonth[year][month];
                const numEvents = events.length;
        
                // Calculate the total width of events for this month
                const totalWidth = numEvents * (bubbleSize + spacingX);
                
                // Calculate the starting X position for this row of events
                const startX = currentX - totalWidth / 2;
                
                events.forEach((event, index) => {
                    const y = currentY + monthIndex * (bubbleSize + spacingY);
                    const x = startX + index * (bubbleSize + spacingX); 
                    console.log(monthIndex, spacingY);
                    console.log('const x: ',x)
                    console.log('const y: ',y)

                    console.log('Rendering bubble at (x, y):', x, y);
                    // Create bubble graphics
                    const bubble = new PIXI.Graphics();
                    const color = timelineColors[allTimelines.findIndex((timeline) => timeline.id === event.timelineId) % timelineColors.length];
                    bubble.beginFill(color);
                    bubble.drawCircle(0, 0, bubbleSize);
                    bubble.endFill();
                    bubble.x = x;
                    bubble.y = y;

                    app.stage.addChild(bubble);

                    // Increment x and y for the next event
                    // currentX += spacingX;
                });
                currentY += spacingY
            });
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (containerRef.current) {
            app = new PIXI.Application({
                width: 400,
                height: 400
            });

            containerRef.current.appendChild(app.view);

            let yOffset = 0;
            const timelines = {};

            allTimelines.forEach(timeline => {
                timelines[timeline.id] = new PIXI.Container();
                app.stage.addChild(timelines[timeline.id])
                timeline.events.sort((a,b) => {
                    const aDate = a.startDate || a.date;
                    const bDate = b.startDate || b.date;
                    return new Date(aDate) - new Date(bDate);
                });
                console.log('Timeline events sorted:', timeline.events);
                yOffset += 20
                renderTimeline(timeline.events, timelines[timeline.id], yOffset);
            });
        }

        // Cleanup function
        return () => {
            if (app) {
                app.destroy(true);
            }
        };
    }, [allTimelines]);

    return (
        <div ref={containerRef} className="pixi-container" style={{
            display:'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            padding: '10px'
        }}>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PixiTimeline2;
```

I'm creating a timeline where it sorts the events by year horizontally and vertically by month. Each timeline will be a different color, but it is prioritizing the events.